# How to download multiple files with Primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a datatable and user will select some files from this table and when he clicks to "download" button, he will download these files. Below code works perfectly but there is a InputStreamList as you can see here and not only first stream but also other streams must be downloaded. Is there any idea?

Here is my controller method;

```
StreamedContent file;

public void downloadFile(){
    InputStream stream = streamList.get(0);
    file = new DefaultStreamedContent(stream, "xml", getRandomName());
}
```

My view;

```
<p:commandButton value="Download"
                         ajax="false"
                         actionListener="#{myController.downloadFile()}"
                         icon="ui-icon-disk">
            <p:fileDownload value="#{myController.file}" />
        </p:commandButton>
```

Comment: @BalusC how to provide them as zip?

Answer (score 0):

Use Javascript to simulate onClick event on each of the file.

### Display files

```
 <p:commandButton  value="Download" ajax="false"  icon="ui-icon-arrowthick-1-s" styleClass="foo">
         <p:fileDownload value="#{fileDownloadView.file}" />
  </p:commandButton>
```

### DownloadAll Button

```
<p:commandButton value="DownloadAll" ajax="false" onclick="start()" icon="ui-icon-arrowthick-1-s"/>
```

### Javascript

```
function start() {                    
                    var buttons = $(".foo");
                    $(buttons).each(function(){
                    $(this).click();
                     });             

                    }
```